# how do i removed NULL group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, null, powerbi

How do I remove the NULL row,
or better yet, assign a unique value to that row, instead of NULL?

can you show me both way?

[image]

i try to use this as a fact table so i can connect a relationship on powerbi
but i got a many to many relationship, i think assigning a value to the NULL might able to solve the problem

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *remove* the `NULL` group, filter it off:

```sql
SELECT HKDATE, COUNT(unitnbr) AS Move_Count
FROM [N4Misc].[dbo].[RMG_MOVEHIST]
WHERE HKDATE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY HKDATE;
```

To *keep* the `NULL` group, but label it as something else, use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10), HKDATE, 120), 'MISSING') AS HKDATE,
       COUNT(unitnbr) AS Move_Count
FROM [N4Misc].[dbo].[RMG_MOVEHIST]
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), HKDATE, 120);
```

Comment: how come when I use the 2nd query, i'm no longer to use a filter
 having count(unitnbr)>100?

Comment: What is the _second_ query?  You should be able to add that `HAVING` clause to my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a where clause. After from, before group by.

```
where not HKDATE is null
```